# Variable Clustering (varclus) R-squared from SAS in R

Tags: r, clustering, sas

I am using the varclus function from the `Hmisc` package in `R`. Are there ways to produce summary tables from varclus like those in `SAS`, containing information like proportion of variance they explain, $R^2$ with own cluster an next closest, etc. I'm especially interested in how to calculate the $R^2$ for own cluster and next closest and $1-R^2$ Ratio after using the varclus function from `Hmisc` package.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture of the tables you want to produce?  Or a link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.